# Codemirror remote autcompletion

Tags: codemirror

Codemirror has a nice example for autocompletion : [link](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html).

The idea is to have server side autocompletion (e.g. Ajax service that autocompletes Java). Does somebody has an example of a remote autocompletion with codemirror ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? it's all client side. the codemirror modes (used for autocompletion) are all javascript programs executed in the browser.

Comment: the suggestion are coming from an Ajax request (server side)

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get async completions working with CodeMirror 5.3's show-hint.js by using the following (es6 flavoured, so for es3, replace `let` with `var` and the `=>` with `function`)

While there's no actual ajax, it's hopefully obvious how to hook that in, just invoke `callback` in your ajax calls completion handler.

```
CodeMirror.registerHelper('hint', 'ajax', (mirror, callback) => {
    let words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    let cur = mirror.getCursor();
    let range = mirror.findWordAt(cur);
    let fragment = mirror.getRange(range.anchor, range.head);
    callback({
        list: words.filter(w => w.indexOf(fragment) === 0),
        from: range.anchor,
        to: range.head
    });
});
CodeMirror.hint.ajax.async = true;

CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(mirror) {
    mirror.showHint({ hint: CodeMirror.hint.ajax });
};
```

Key is to set the `async` property as the docs tells you to:

> It is possible to set the async property on a hinting function to
>   true, in which case it will be called with arguments (cm, callback,
>   ?options), and the completion interface will only be popped up when
>   the hinting function calls the callback

Answer (score 0):

```
// javascript code

var editor;

function createEditor (data) {
    editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
        mode: "text/x-sql",
        extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": "autocomplete"},
        hint: CodeMirror.hint.sql,
        hintOptions: {
            tables: data ? data : {}
        }
    })
}

(function createEditorWithRemoteData () {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        url:'data.json',
        success:createEditor,
        error:function () {}
    })
})();

// data.json

{
    "table1": [ "col_A", "col_B", "col_C" ],
    "table2": [ "other_columns1", "other_columns2" ]
}
```

Comment: This implies a fixed completion list